# Remove event click in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, onclick, dom-events, onclicklistener

I have two functions to open and close `sidenav`. I added feature, when you click outside nav you trigger function `closeNav()`. Sidenav is closed, but event click is still on whole `document`, so I have to `removeEventListener`. I've tried a lot but no attempt was effective. Any ideas how to do this?

JS

```
//  Show sidenav 
var sideNav = document.getElementById('rizkSidenav');

function openNav() {
    sideNav.style.width = "83%";

    // Close nav when clicked outside 
    document.addEventListener("click", function(evt) {  
        targetElement = evt.target;  // clicked element
        do {
            if (targetElement === sideNav) {
            // This is a click inside. Do nothing, just return.
                return;
            }
            // Go up the DOM
            targetElement = targetElement.parentNode;
        } while (targetElement);
        // This is a click outside.
        closeNav();
    });
}

function closeNav() {
    sideNav.style.width = "0";
    //????? (event listener should be removed)
    document.removeEventListener("click", function(evt){});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it is not the same function.
Try this on:

```
var sideNav = document.getElementById('rizkSidenav');

var myFunction = function(evt) {  
        targetElement = evt.target;  // clicked element
        do {
            if (targetElement === sideNav) {
            // This is a click inside. Do nothing, just return.
                return;
            }
            // Go up the DOM
            targetElement = targetElement.parentNode;
        } while (targetElement);
        // This is a click outside.
        closeNav();
    }

function openNav() {
    sideNav.style.width = "83%";

    // Close nav when clicked outside 
    document.addEventListener("click", myFunction);
}

function closeNav() {
    sideNav.style.width = "0";
    //????? (event listener should be removed)
    document.removeEventListener("click", myFunction);
}
```